# Is there a Code Complete Quiz/Test?

Tags: knowledge-management, code-complete

So, my boss for very good reason LOVES the book Code Complete by Steve Mcconnell. I was wondering if anyone has ever come across a way to test if someone has read the book. I swore a quiz/test had to be online somewhere. Alas, my efforts to find one were futile. We are starting a Gameification process of developer seniority. We are giving a list of code achievements that can result in bonuses and benefits. One of the achievements is to read Code Complete. One of my personal achievements is to find a definitive way to test if someone has read it.

This seems ambiguous but there is a definitive answer(s).

TLDR:
Does anybody know of a quiz or test about Code Complete? If you do not, what single question would you ask someone, to determine if they read Code Complete?

Some of my Questions: ("I like these but I am looking for that one definitive question")

```
What is Cohesion, why is it important?
When should code go in to it's own method? 
When should a collection of methods become a class? 
How much should you plan a project out before doing it? 
What is Code Construction? 
Give an example of a variable name for an investment amount.
```

To clarify, I am not looking for a summary or even an answer. I simply would like a premade quiz or a single question to ask someone. Thanks so much guys.

Comment: I found this on google but it is pretty sub par http://quiz.thefullwiki.org/Code_Complete#quiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coding practices should unroll with time as they're applied, but if you're looking for a quick "Did you read this?" then I'd pick one of the funny comments McConnell has peppered in there, like:

> Under what conditions would you be a pompous fraud?
>
> What musical composer died in the comments?

And so forth.  These would more than likely stick out if you read the book like a novel (which I think can be done -- I enjoyed it!) rather than just skimmed the headings.